# How to return the point of lines crossing? Lines don't always intersect

Tags: c++, function, exception, return, return-value

Let's say we want to make a function which calculates the intersection point of two lines. The intersection point is't always defined or unique. How to reflect that in the function's signature?

I have come up with these options:

1. `bool getIntersectionPoint ( Line& a, Line& b , Point& result );`

   Returns false if lines are parallel. Otherwise returns true and writes result to the variable.
2. `Point getIntersectionPoint ( Line& a, Line& b );`

   Throws an exception if lines are parallel.

*[update]*
If we make 2 functions `bool doLinesIntersect(const Line&, const Line&);` and `Point twoLinesIntersection(const Line&, const Line&);` the second one can still be called after the first returns false.

Comment: I highly doubt you want to throw an exception for this.

Comment: I think throwing an exception would be wrong – since two lines being parallel and therefor not having an intersection is not an “error”, but a normal result.

Comment: There is no "best" way. There can be arguments for both approaches (especially since you provide no context).

Comment: The first function will only return the boolean value as "True" or "False". So I guess it wont give you any idea about the point at which the lines are getting intersected. The second function will give you the point at which the line are intersecting therefore it is throwing exception when lines are parallel.

This depends upon the return value consideration.. I guess, second function with some modification will work better than the first one..

Comment: Make sure that you're not returning a reference to a local Point!

Comment: If you choose the first solution (the one I prefer), your method should probably be called something like `calculateIntersectionPoint`. There also is a third possibility: returning a special value that means that no intersection exists. In Java, you could just return `null`. In C++, it could be a `std::pair<bool,Point>` (I wouldn't return a pointer in C++).

Comment: @Axel a variant on your last suggestion is to return an optional type, such as `boost::optional<Point>`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yep. And it's also a better variant.

Comment: This question **does not** *solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion*, and **is** *supported by references* (see links to available sum types from Boost in the accepted answer). The decision to close it isn't justified IMO; I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: `Not constructive`? Really?

Comment: "What is the best practice nowadays?" questions are not constructive. Just look at the accepted answer: 'I **suggest** to use...'

Comment: @WouterJ the question is `How to reflect that in the function's signature?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO, line intersection yields object, that's why it would be honest to have

`boost::variant<Empty, Point, Line> intersect(Line const & l1, Line const & l2)`

and helper functions, like

`boost::optional<Point> getIntersectionPoint(Line const & l1, Line const & l2)`

`bool isParallel(Line const & l1, Line const & l2)`

**Edit:**
If you do not want to use boost library you can easily create simple analogues:

```
struct intersection_result_t
{
  enum isec_t
  {
    isec_empty, isec_point, isec_line
  }

  intersection_result_t()
    : type_(isec_empty)
  {
    new (storage_) Empty();
  }

  intersection_result_t(Empty const & e)
    : type_(isec_empty)
  {
    new (storage_) Empty(e);
  }
  intersection_result_t(Point const & p)
    : type_(isec_point)
  {
    new (storage_) Point(p);
  }
...
  intersection_result_t(intersection_result_t & ir)
    : type_(ir.type_)
  {
    switch(ir.type_)
    {
      case isec_empty:
        new (storage_) Empty(*static_cast<Empty*>(ir.storage_));
      case ....
    }
  }
private:
  void destroy()
  {
    switch(type_)
    {
      case isec_empty:
        operator delete (static_cast<Empty*>(storage_), storage_);
      case ....
    }
  }
private:
  char storage_[MAX(sizeof(Empty), sizeof(Point), sizeof(Line))];
  isec_t type_;
};
```

etc, etc some more switches needed. Or you can use templates.
For optional just use `initialized_` instead of `type_` to track construction state.

Comment: Can you (easily) do something like this without the boost library?

Comment: The edit is not sufficient. There is no guarantee that the `storage_` will be aligned correctly. Use [std::aligned_storage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage).

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by **ulidtko**, it would be good to return an object that "may be a Point". In C++ you can use [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)

```
boost::optional<Point> getIntersectionPoint(const Line& a, const Line& b) {
    // ...
    if (there_is_zero_or_inifinty_points_of_intersection)
        return boost::optional<Point>();
    else
        return boost::optional<Point>(the_point_of_intersection);
}
```

You can think of `boost::optional<Point>` as if it was a `Point*`. In particular, a client can query if the intersection returned is a proper point or not in this way:

```
boost::optional<Point> point = getIntersectionPoint(a, b);
if (point)
    // point "points to" a proper Point which can be retrieved as *point
else
    // point is "NULL", that is, there's no unique point of intersection
```

Funnily enough, the motivating example of [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) is also a geometric problem. This is not a coincidence since the `boost::optional` author, I believe, writes geometric software. ;-)

It's worth mentioning that there's a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3527.html) to include `optional` to the STL in the next revision of the C++ standard.

Comment: It is a pity though that you'll have to surround each and every usage of such a value with `if () {} else {}`, which could become a bit of annoyance. As we have no monads in C++, an exception-throwing approach might win in some cases with its code clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel lines are not an error, or unexpected. Therefore throwing an exception is not appropriate.

BTW this is preferable as a function signature.

```
bool getIntersectionPoint(const Line& a, const Line& b, Point& result);
```

Specifying const makes it clear that the function does not modify it's first two arguments, and also allows you to call the function with temporaries.

Comment: The method is called `getIntersectionPoint()`, so not being able to calculate one (since the lines are parallel) **could** be treated as error

Comment: That parallel lines do not intersect is well known. So I think anyone calling getIntersectionPoint would understand that they have to look out for them and that the function is not providing any guarantees that an intersection point will be found.

Comment: To be fair the original question called the function getIntersectionPoint so its somewhat unfair to mark this down based upon that.

Answer (score 0):

From the abstraction (API) perspective, you have two unrelated functions:

```
bool doLinesIntersect(const Line&, const Line&);
```

and

```
Point twoLinesIntersection(const Line&, const Line&);
```

The second function must assume that the lines do actually intersect (and aren't collinear). *If you don't trust your callers*, you may want to throw an exception indicating that preconditions aren't met.

Comment: This is certainly a valid third way. It has some upside. However, the downside is that you may end up performing the same work twice.

Comment: This approach is not good IMHO. What would `twoLinesIntersection` do if it can not find the result? E.g. if I still call it after `doLinesIntersect` returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Your second function should probably not return a Point& but a Point value (who owns it?)

Alternatively, there is a 3rd option:

```
Point getIntersectionPoint ( Line& a, Line& b, bool* ok );
```

If you provide a NULL pointer for 'ok', throw if there is no intersection otherwise return false in the value of 'ok'.

I would suggest that for a function like this, it is better to avoid exceptions entirely.  A non-intersection is not really all that exceptional and exceptions should really be reserved fro stuff that is unexpected.  You can expect non-intersecting lines.

Use the version that returns bool, or the version with a bool argument but don't throw.

EDIT
A fourth option that is often used:

```
std::pair<bool, Point> getIntersectionPoint ( Line& a, Line& b );
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a very good motivation for easier **[sum types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_type)** in C++.

In a language like Haskell your function would've had the following signature:

```
getIntersectionPoint :: Line -> Line -> Maybe Point
```

where [`Maybe Point`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Maybe) (the return type of the function) essentially means a type which can have two values: `Nothing` or `Just p`, where `p` is a `Point`.

Availability of such *easy* sum types actually would've made the question unnessesary at all, because all approaches would've merge into a single one.

---

Edit: [this answer](/a/15634199/531179) demonstrates neatly that Boost offers easy sum types facilities. There are [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/libs/optional/) and [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/libs/variant/). Sweet.

Answer (score -1):

Without given the context people will discuss without end.

Supouse you want to use the function inside some

```
fillWithColor(color c, set_of lines& figure);
```

and somehow you use `getLinesIntersection` to do that. If you need to check each call not only will your code a mess, but you don’t know what to do with the error. Simple use the function and let the caller catch the exception.

In other context you can implement:

```
bool doLinesIntersect(const Line&, const Line2&, Point &p);
Point getLinesIntersection(const Line&, const Line2&)
{
   Point p;
   If (! doLinesIntersect(Line, Line2,p) throw …;
   return p;
}
```

Both aproach are very valid !!!